# Segmentation fault:Adding void pointer node to list

Tags: c, function-pointers, doubly-linked-list

Hey am trying to implement a generic list iterator that can store elements of any type.It has other files to tackle positive integer types and string types.However,I am receiving an error stating that theres segmentation fault when trying to add in integer nodes when running test case file.Theres void pointer being used to add in the elements as the test input is also inclusive of strings but for this case i cant even add integer values to start.I am using a linux environment and the errors are indicative at run time.Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "iteratorG.h"

typedef struct Node {

  char   *value;  // value of thee list item (string)
  struct Node *prev;
  // pointer previous node in list
  struct Node *next;
  // pointer to next node in list

  // implemented struct here .. 
} Node;

typedef struct IteratorGRep {

  int  numofit;      // count of items in list
  Node *head;      // first node in list
  Node *elem;
  Node *curr;       // current node in list
  Node *tail;       // last node in list

  ElmCompareFp  cmpElm;
  ElmNewFp  newElm;
  ElmFreeFp freeElm;

  // implemented struct here .. 

} IteratorGRep;


/*


  // functions below .... 
 */


IteratorG newIterator(ElmCompareFp cmpFp, ElmNewFp newFp, ElmFreeFp freeFp){

  IteratorG it;

  it = malloc(sizeof (struct IteratorGRep));
  assert (it != NULL);
  it->numofit = 0;
  it->head = NULL;
  it->elem=NULL;
  it->tail = NULL;
  it->curr = NULL;
  it->cmpElm=cmpFp;
  it->newElm=newFp;
  it->freeElm=freeFp;
  return it;

    // created list 
}

int  add(IteratorG it, void *vp){

  Node *vep=NULL;
  vep->value=it->newElm(vp);

  if(it==NULL)
  {
    it->head=vep;
    it->curr->prev=NULL;
    it->curr->next=NULL;
    return 1;

  }
  Node *temp=NULL;
  temp=it->next;
  it->next=vep;
  vep->prev=it;
  vep->next=temp;
  temp->prev=vep;

    // Inserts element pointed by 'vp' into list iterator 'it' 
    return 1;
}
int  hasNext(IteratorG it){

  if(it->curr->next!=NULL)
   {
     return 1;
   }

    // check for any next elements  
    return 0;
}
int  hasPrevious(IteratorG it){

    if(it->curr->prev!=NULL)
    {
      return 1;
    }
    // check for any previous elements 
    return 0;
}
void *next(IteratorG it){
  if(it->curr->next!=NULL)
  {
    it->curr=it->curr->next;
    Node *curre=it->curr;
    return curre;

  }
    // move to next element
    return NULL;
}
void *previous(IteratorG it){

    if(it->curr->prev!=NULL)
    {
      it->curr=it->curr->prev;
      Node *curre=it->curr;
      return curre;

    }

    // moves to previous element
    return NULL;
}
int  del(IteratorG it){
  if(it->prev!=NULL)
  {
    Node *temp_curr=it->curr;
    Node *temp_prev=it->curr->prev->prev;
    temp_curr->prev=temp_prev;
    temp_prev->next=temp_curr;
    return 1;

  }
     // removes previous element from list 
  if(it->prev==NULL)
  {
    return 0;
  }
}
int  set(IteratorG it, void *vp){
  if(it->prev!=NULL)
  {
  Node *vep=NULL;
  vep->value=it->newElm(vp);
  Node *store_curr=it->curr;
  Node *store_prev=it->curr->prev->prev;

  store_curr->prev=vep;
  vep->next=store_curr;
  store_prev->next=vep;
  vep->prev=store_prev;
  return 1;
  }
    // Replaces previous element with the element (*vp) 
    return 0;
}
IteratorG advance(IteratorG it, int n){


    // Advance by n times and return list with n times of elements
    // To  implement function here and change return value 
    return NULL;
}
void reverse(IteratorG it){
  Node *curr = it->head;
  Node *temp = NULL;
  while(curr != NULL) {
    temp = curr->next;
    curr->next = curr->prev;
    curr->prev = temp;
    curr = temp;
  }
  temp = it->head;
  it->head = it->tail;
  it->tail = temp;    

    // reverses order of list  
}
IteratorG find(IteratorG it, int (*fp) (void *vp) ){

    // finds elements after current position,append to new list
    // To implement function here and change return value 

     return NULL;
}

int distanceFromStart(IteratorG it){

  Node *c=it->curr;
  int count=0;

  while(c->prev!=NULL)
  {
    c=c->prev;
    count++;
  }
  return count;

     // counts number of nodes from current position to start of list 

}
int distanceToEnd(IteratorG it){

  Node *cu=it->curr;
  int count=0;

  while(cu->next!=NULL)
  {
    cu=cu->next;
    count++;
  }
  return count;
    // counts number of nodes from current position to end of list  

}
void reset(IteratorG it){

  it->curr=it->head;

    // reset to start of list  
    return;
}
void freeIt(IteratorG it){
  assert(it != NULL);
  Node *curr, *prev;
  curr = it->head;
  while (curr != NULL) {
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
    free(prev->value);
    free(prev);
  }
  free(it); 

    // remove nodes in it and free memory  

}
```

This is the header file for the code:

```
#ifndef LISTITERATORG_H
#define LISTITERATORG_H

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct IteratorGRep *IteratorG;

typedef int   (*ElmCompareFp)(void const *e1, void const *e2);
typedef void *(*ElmNewFp)(void const *e1);
typedef void  (*ElmFreeFp)(void *e1);


IteratorG newIterator(ElmCompareFp cmpFp, ElmNewFp newFp, ElmFreeFp freeFp);
int  add(IteratorG it, void *vp);
int  hasNext(IteratorG it);
int  hasPrevious(IteratorG it);
void *next(IteratorG it);
void *previous(IteratorG it);
int  del(IteratorG it);
int  set(IteratorG it, void *vp);
IteratorG advance(IteratorG it, int n);
void reverse(IteratorG it);
IteratorG find(IteratorG it, int (*fp) (void *vp) );
int distanceFromStart(IteratorG it);
int distanceToEnd(IteratorG it);
void reset(IteratorG it);
void freeIt(IteratorG it);

#endif
```

One of the functions have yet to be implemented and are indicated in the code itself.But i guess that might not be the source of issue here.I perceive that the Node is not being utilised properly here.

EDIT:
heres the test case code.The test case code works perfectly fine:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "iteratorG.h"
#include "positiveIntType.h"
#include "stringType.h" 

#define MAXARRAY 5

/* Helper Functions Below */

/* Returns 1 if marks >= 50, 0 otherwise  */
int passMarks(void *marks){
  return (*((int *) marks) >= 50); 

  /* Easy to understand below .. 
     int *ip = (int *) marks;
     if(*ip >= 50) { return 1; }
     else { return 0; } 
  */
}

/* Returns 1 if str starts with "jo" */
int prefixJo(void *str){
  return (strncmp("jo", (char *) str, 2) == 0) ; 
}

/* A function to print a string from a void pointer */
void prnStr(void *vp){
  assert(vp != NULL);
  printf(" %s", (char *) vp );      
}

/* A function to print an integer from a void pointer */
void prnInt(void *vp){
  assert(vp != NULL);
  printf(" %d", *((int *) vp) );    
}

/* Prints previous element using the given function 'fp'
   examples: prnPrev(it1, prnInt); prnPrev(it2, prnStr);
*/
void prnPrev(IteratorG it, void (*fp) (void *p) ){
  void *prevP = previous(it);
  assert(prevP != NULL);
  printf("> Previous value is: "); 
  fp(prevP);
  printf("\n"); 
}

/* Prints next element using the given function 'fp'
   examples:   prnNext(it1, prnInt); prnNext(it2, prnStr);
*/
void prnNext(IteratorG it, void (*fp) (void *p) ){
  void *nextP = next(it);
  assert(nextP != NULL);
  printf("> Next value is: "); 
  fp(nextP);
  printf("\n"); 
}

/* Prints elements of 'it' from current to last position 
   using the given function 'fp'. The current position 
   of 'it' will change to the end of the list.
   examples: prnIt(it1, prnInt); prnIt(it2, prnStr);
*/
void prnIt(IteratorG it, void (*fp) (void *p) ){
  int count = 0;
  while(hasNext(it)){
    void *nextP = next(it); 
    count++;
    if(count > 1) { printf(", "); }
    fp(nextP);      
  }
  printf("\n"); 
}


/* Few Tests Below  */

void test1(){
  printf("\n--====  Test-01       ====------\n");
  IteratorG it1 = newIterator(positiveIntCompare, positiveIntNew,  positiveIntFree);
  int a[MAXARRAY] = { 25, 78, 6, 82 , 11};
  for(int i=0; i<MAXARRAY; i++){
    int result = add(it1 , &a[i]); 
    printf("> Inserting %d: %s \n", a[i], (result==1 ? "Success" : "Failed") );
  }
  freeIt(it1);
  printf("--====  End of Test-01 ====------\n");
}

void test2(){
  printf("\n--====  Test-02       ====------\n");
  IteratorG it1 = newIterator(positiveIntCompare, positiveIntNew, positiveIntFree);
  int a[MAXARRAY] = { 72, 14, 62, 8, 93};
  for(int i=0; i<MAXARRAY; i++){
    int result = add(it1 , &a[i]); 
    printf("> Inserting %d: %s \n", a[i], (result==1 ? "Success" : "Failed") );
  }

  prnNext(it1, prnInt);
  prnNext(it1, prnInt);
  prnPrev(it1, prnInt);

  int newVal1 = 55;
  int result1 = set(it1, &newVal1);
  printf("> Set value: %d ; return val: %d \n", newVal1,  result1 );  

  prnPrev(it1, prnInt);

  freeIt(it1);
  printf("--====  End of Test-02 ====------\n");
}

void test3(){
  printf("\n--====  Test-03       ====------\n");
  IteratorG it1 = newIterator(positiveIntCompare, positiveIntNew, positiveIntFree);
  int a[MAXARRAY] = { 04, 54, 15, 12, 34};
  for(int i=0; i<MAXARRAY; i++){
    int result = add(it1 , &a[i]); 
    printf("> Inserting %d: %s \n", a[i], (result==1 ? "Success" : "Failed") );
  }

  reset(it1);
  printf("> it1 (after reset): \n");
  prnIt(it1, prnInt);
  reset(it1);

  IteratorG advIt1 = advance(it1, 4);
  printf("> advance(it1, 4) returns: \n");
  prnIt(advIt1, prnInt);

  IteratorG advIt2 = advance(it1, -3);
  printf("> advance(it1, -3) returns: \n");
  prnIt(advIt2, prnInt);

  printf("> In 'it1', ");
  prnPrev(it1, prnInt);

  freeIt(it1);
  freeIt(advIt1);
  freeIt(advIt2);

  printf("--====  End of Test-03 ====------\n");
}

 void test4(){
  printf("\n--====  Test-04       ====------\n");
  IteratorG it1 = newIterator(positiveIntCompare, positiveIntNew, positiveIntFree);
  int a[MAXARRAY] = { 97, 10, 61, 73, 47};
  for(int i=0; i<MAXARRAY; i++){
    int result = add(it1 , &a[i]); 
    printf("> Inserting %d: %s \n", a[i], (result==1 ? "Success" : "Failed") );
  }

  reset(it1);
   printf("> it1 (after reset): \n");
  prnIt(it1, prnInt);
  reset(it1);

  IteratorG findIt1 = find(it1, passMarks);
  printf("> find(it1, passMarks) returns: \n");
  prnIt(findIt1, prnInt);

  printf("> In 'it1', \n");
  prnNext(it1, prnInt);
  prnNext(it1, prnInt);

  int delResult = del(it1);
  printf("\n> del(it1) results in the following and returns %d: \n", delResult );
  reset(it1);
  printf("> it1 (after reset): \n");
  prnIt(it1, prnInt);

  freeIt(it1);
  freeIt(findIt1);

  printf("--====  End of Test-04 ====------\n");
}


void test5(){
  printf("\n--====  Test-05       ====------\n");
  IteratorG it = newIterator(stringCompare, stringNew, stringFree);

  char *strA[MAXARRAY];
  strA[0] = strdup("joe");
  strA[1] = strdup("rita");
  strA[2] = strdup("john");
  strA[3] = strdup("abby"); 
  strA[4] = strdup("peter"); 

  int j;
  for(j=0; j<MAXARRAY; j++){
    int result = add(it , strA[j]); 
    printf("> Inserting %s: %s \n", strA[j], (result==1 ? "Success" : "Failed") );
  }

  prnNext(it, prnStr);
  prnNext(it, prnStr);
  prnPrev(it, prnStr);

  char *newStr1 = "sydney";
  int result2 = set(it, newStr1);
  printf("> Set value: %s ; return val: %d \n", newStr1,  result2 );  

  prnPrev(it, prnStr);

  freeIt(it);
  printf("--====  End of Test-05 ====------\n");
}


void test6(){
  printf("\n--====  Test-06       ====------\n");
  IteratorG it = newIterator(stringCompare, stringNew, stringFree);

  char *strA[MAXARRAY];
  strA[0] = strdup("kylie");
  strA[1] = strdup("lian");
  strA[2] = strdup("john");
  strA[3] = strdup("arnav"); 
  strA[4] = strdup("joe"); 

  int j;
  for(j=0; j<MAXARRAY; j++){
    int result = add(it , strA[j]); 
    printf("> Inserting %s: %s \n", strA[j], (result==1 ? "Success" : "Failed") );
  }

  reset(it);
  printf("> it (after reset): \n");
  prnIt(it, prnStr);
  reset(it);

  IteratorG advIt3 = advance(it, 3);
  printf("> advance(it, 3) returns: \n");
  prnIt(advIt3, prnStr);

  IteratorG advIt4 = advance(it, -2);
  printf("> advance(it, -2) returns: \n");
  prnIt(advIt4, prnStr);

  reset(it);
  printf("> it (after reset): \n");
  prnIt(it, prnStr);
  reset(it);

  IteratorG findit = find(it, prefixJo);
  printf("> find(it, prefixJo) returns: \n");
  prnIt(findit, prnStr);
  printf("\n> In 'it',  \n");
  prnNext(it, prnStr);
  prnNext(it, prnStr);

  freeIt(it);
  freeIt(findit);
  freeIt(advIt3);
  freeIt(advIt4);
  printf("--====  End of Test-06 ====------\n\n");
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


  test1();
  //test2();
  //test3();
  //test4();
  //test5();
  //test6();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And also please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: A hint though: `Node *vep=NULL;` directly followed by `vep->value=...`? You also dereference `it` *before* checking if it is a null pointer. You have *many* of those problems.

Comment: The naming seems very odd, as far as I know "iterate" basically means "loop"; you can iterate over a list, but a list cannot be called an iterator. Very confusing.